# Force Wordpress media library to index files uploaded from ACF file upload field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've created an ACF file upload field, in order to attach pdf and image files to each post I create.
the problem is, when I want to Re-Use those files - they don't appear in the media library, but they do appear in the "uploads" folder on the server.
Is there a way to force the media library to index those files?

Comment: Not sure why this has been demoted; I've had a similar problem when bulk updating posts that have a file attachment.

Answer (score 0):

They certainly should be appearing in the media library so it sounds like a configuration issue. Are there any errors appearing when you upload the file? Perhaps also check your server logs to make sure there is nothing being reported when you try and upload the file...